# How do I translate my own binary-like language into two different functions?

Tags: javascript

I have made up a kind of binary but with 0's and 1's in different orders. e.g. 10000 is A (Each letter being 5 numbers). I have a phone sending a string of these numbers to the computer. What I need the computer to do is make an LED (attached to it) blink for every 0 and dash for every 1.

---How would I translate the 0's and 1's into blink and dash functions?---

(I've already coded out the functions, just how would I decipher the 1's and 0's in the string to call the functions in order? The function names are "do" for dot and "da" for dash)

Comment: Too broad question. There is a lot of information missing so nobody will be able to help you. Try explaining the server, post some code, explain the expect input/output, etc. And also, a phone sending the signals? How?

Comment: possibly [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) can help. But i don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: Make a loop.  In the loop, read a symbol(s) from the input, interpret it into the correct function using an if/else or a switch, and call that function.  Repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tough to give you an exact answer because of the lack of information, but here's one way to do it.

Convert the integer to a string and then process it character by character. If you want to wait out between the function calls you can add a `setTimeout`

```
function processInput(num){
    str = num+""; //convert the number to a string
    for(var i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
        var currentChar = str.charAt(i);
        if(currentChar === "0"){
            setTimeout(function(){
                do();
            }, (100 * i)); //wait 100ms per character
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                da();
            }, (100 * i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also do `for(let currentChar of str){..}` to be a bit cleaner.

Comment: @KarlReid I edited my answer to make use of the index for a call to `setTimeout`. Personally I'm a proponent of always using long-form for loops because it's easier to modify them later.